# Is there a way to get all the jobs started by the particular plugin in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to get all the jobs started by the particular plugin in eclipse?
Here we run eclipse in command line mode. We start few jobs in a plugin. At some case the plugin terminates even before the job is completed. It has been decided to wait for all the jobs started by the particular plugin in Activator.stop(). I was wondering whether there's a possibility to get all the jobs started by a particular plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override a Job class something like this.

```
public class MyPluginJob extends Job
{
    private String jobFamily;

    public MyPluginJob(String name, String jobFamily)
    {
        super(name);
        this.jobFamily = jobFamily;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean belongsTo(Object family)
    {
        return this.jobFamily.equals(family);
    }
}
```

And, you will be starting your jobs with the family name

```
Job job = new MyPluginJob("Update info", "Your_plugin_job_family_name")
        {
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
            {
                //do whatever you want
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };
job.schedule();
```

Now, get all your plugin jobs by doing this call 
This will return all the jobs owned by a plugin

```
Job[] allJobs =Job.getJobManager().find("Your_plugin_job_family_name");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can wait for jobs in a particular job family to finish using:

```
Job.getJobManager().join(jobFamily, progressMonitor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create Job by specifying Job's family as below:

```
//create constant job family
final static String MY_JOB_FAMILY = "myPluginJob";

//Create Job
Job job = new Job("Job name") {
  @Override
  protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    //perform the task
  }

  @Override 
  public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
       return family.equals(MY_JOB_FAMILY);
                                          };
}
job.schedule();
```

In Activator.stop() call waitForJob(MY_JOB_FAMILY)

```
@Override
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
     waitForJob(MY_JOB_FAMILY);
     //Do other shut down activities
}

public void waitForJob(String jobFamily) {
    IJobManager jobManager = Job.getJobManager();
    Job[] jobs = jobManager.find(jobFamily);
    //Wait for all jobs belongs to family 'jobFamily'
    while(jobs.length > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Do nothing.
        }
        jobs = jobManager.find(jobFamily);
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.